# How to implement something like a wizard screen?

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form

I want to place a "Next" button which , when clicked , will display another group of components ; and I want also to place a "Previous" button which , when clicked , then display the previous group of components. How to achieve that ?

Comment: It's 2 screens? or one screen that you change his Components?

Comment: It's 2 screens? or one screen that you want to change his Components?

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented forms for data entry. Typically i have a wizard class that holds all the forms in the wizard, so i can easily navigate back and forth between them. And when i call a new form, i pass along the object of the wizard.

Below is my wizard, with implementation omitted.

```
public final class ReportWizard {

    public static ReportWizard instance = null;
    Form parent = null;
    Form titleForm = null;
    Form budgetForm = null;
    Form iconForm = null;

    final Report reports[] = new Report[20];

    public ReportWizard(Form parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.instance = this;
    }

    void getTitle() {
        AddReportForm reportForm = new AddReportForm(parent, this);
        reportForm.showReportForm();
        titleForm = reportForm;
        ImageListPicker getIcon = new ImageListPicker(titleForm, reports, this);
        iconForm = getIcon.imageListForm;
    }

    void getIcon() {
        iconForm.show();        
    }

    public void cancelWizard() {

        titleForm = null;
        iconForm = null;
        budgetForm = null;
        instance = null;

        parent.show();
        parent = null;
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to go to next "screen" ? In fact the number of screens is the number of records from recorstore.

Comment: Could you give some more details about the solution you want? I would not suggest you create too many Forms. Probably you can just do a removeAll() on the current form and reload the screen with new components. This will be a better solution than having many forms.